# Get query result as array in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a query, how do I get the result as an array?

```
function get_all_transaksi_proses() {
    $rs = $this->db->query("SELECT a.id_transaksi,
                                   a.nama,
                                   a.tgl_transaksi, 
                                   (SELECT COUNT( id_transaksi ) AS jum  
                                     FROM  tbl_detail_trs_menu  
                                     WHERE id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi)  AS jumlah, 
                                   a.status_transaksi, 
                                   a.total, 
                                   b.status_pelanggan, 
                                   c.nama_karyawan 

                            FROM   tbl_transaksi a 

                                   LEFT JOIN  tbl_pelanggan b 
                                      ON a.id_pelanggan = b.id_pelanggan 

                                   LEFT JOIN tbl_karyawan c 
                                      ON a.id_karyawan = c.id_karyawan 

                            WHERE  a.status_transaksi =  'PROSES' ");  

  echo json_encode(array("result" => $rs)); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$rs = $this->db->query(...);
$array = $rs->result_array();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: @user3012773 eh? there's no `preg_match()` in the code that you're showing. is that somewhere else in your code? don't think it has anything to do with this question.

Comment: but i think this error from my query, because I run the query directly on routes codeigniter.. can help me

Comment: That error should also tell you which php file and what line number its coming from. Without seeing all of your code its impossible for me to know.

Comment: function index() {
        $this->model_transaksi->get_all_transaksi_proses();
    }

Comment: that code in control , i can get the data, but warning :
Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Comment: mysql/mysql_driver.php load in codeigniter, don'y my php. btw thx u @jszobody

Comment: What is `$this->db`? Is that a DB class that you wrote, or the CodeIgnitor DB class? Ensure that you are passing CodeIgnitor a simple SQL string, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

To get a result in array you have to do this CI 2.2.2:

```
    return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db->query("select....");

return $query->result(); // it will result an array
or
echo json_encode($query->result()); // this will also result array but direct to json_encode
```

....hope i help you!